# Showing intellij command line arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a java app that loads an enormous data set into memory (don't ask - it's messy). This app runs fine in the IntelliJ debugger but gives OOM (out of memory errors) when I try to run it as a compiled .jar file.

How would I find out the params that IntelliJ is using to run it? Looking at the process list didn't reveal anything promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line in the Run toolwindow in IntelliJ IDEA shows the exact command line used to run the program, including all VM options.

Comment: This sounds spot on but Im not seeing it. "menu" / "run" (or "debug") / ?

Comment: If you're using the "Debug" button to run your application, switch to the Console tab in the debugger.

Comment: Wow - pages and pages of .jar files - and not an `Xmx` or similar in sight. Go figure.

Comment: There won't be a `-Xmx` if you didn't specify it in the "VM options" field of your run configuration.

Comment: Which I didn't.. which is why this is a tad mysterious. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do something like this:

```
java -jar -Xmx2048m myJar.jar
```

The xmx flag should allow you to add more memory for your jar to work with. You can just up this until it works.